# Can I statically link a package created with C++Builder (containing classes) into a Delphi EXE?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

Can I statically link a package created with C++Builder (containing classes) into a Delphi `.exe`?

The example in [CodeRage2016/David Millington - Mixing Delphi and C++](https://github.com/Embarcadero/CodeRage2016/tree/master/David%20Millington%20-%20Mixing%20Delphi%20and%20C%2B%2B) (the Delphi calling C++ example) creates an abstract class in Delphi and an implementation in C++Builder. C++Builder creates a `.bpl` which is loaded dynamically by the Delphi app. Is it possible to instead statically link the C++ package?

```pascal
type
  TAbstractClass = class
  protected
    function GetText : string; virtual; abstract;
    procedure SetText(Value : string); virtual; abstract;
  public
    procedure DoSomething; virtual; abstract;
    property Text : string read GetText write SetText;
  end;

  function CreateCppDescendant : TAbstractClass; stdcall; external 'CPPPackage.bpl';
```

The abstract class is implemented in the C++Builder package:

```cpp
#ifndef CPPClassH
#define CPPClassH

#include "DelphiAbstractClass.hpp"
#include <vector>

class __declspec(delphiclass) TCppClass : public TAbstractClass
{
private:
    String m_Text;
    std::vector<int> m_Vector;
protected:
    virtual System::UnicodeString __fastcall GetText();
    virtual void __fastcall SetText(System::UnicodeString Value);
public:
    __fastcall TCppClass();
    __fastcall virtual ~TCppClass();

    virtual void __fastcall DoSomething();
    __property System::UnicodeString Text = {read=GetText};
};

#endif
```

Comment: `.bpl`s are just special `.dll`s and thus can only be loaded dynamically. That being said, C++Builder does have the option of making `.obj` and `.lib` files for static linking of the units inside a package, but I don't know if Delphi can consume those (it can consume `.obj`s via [`{$L}`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Link_object_file_(Delphi)), but that is typically used for linking to C-compatible APIs, I'm not sure if it will work for C++ classes).

Comment: Indeed, I was wondering if there was another option - like the .dpk in Delphi, but doesn't seem that way. I suppose the only way is to make a 'flat' C api for the C++ code and then wrap it in an object wrapper in Delphi. Thanks

Comment: `.dpk` is the project file. Perhaps you are thinking of `.dcp` or `.dcu` instead? The C++ equivalent is `.lib`/`.a` and `.obj`, respectively.

Comment: No. C++Builder can use Delphi classes, but the reverse isn't possible. Support was added to Builder so that it could use the VCL (and later FMX), but nothing was added to Delphi to do the reverse. That's why you can't write components in Builder and use them in Delphi.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes .dcp I meant